# Unexpected behavior with CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, pug

I'm making a series of buttons to practice with CSS and this is what I have

https://codepen.io/buoyantair/pen/JNgqXG?editors=1100

Now there are a few weird things happening in that CSS so, lemme just put the code here

Pug Script

```
    header.row
        .col
            h1 Hover Buttons
            p A small variation of buttions I made.
            p Made by <a href="https://codepen.io/buoyantair">@buoyantair</a>
    .row
        button.btn Hello
        button.btn-ghost World
        button.btn-pill Cat
    .row
        button.btn-fall Kitty
        button.btn-hang World
        button.btn-wobble Cat
```

Sass file

```
    =flex($direction, $position)
        display: flex
        flex-flow: $direction
        justify-content: $position

    =size($width, $height)
        width: $width
        height: $height

    $color-theme: #DD403A
    $btn-width: 100px
    $btn-height: 50px

    body
        +size(100%, 100vh)
        background: #3E363F
        +flex(column wrap, space-around)
        color: #FFF
        font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif
        font-size: 1.5em
    a,a:visited, a:active
        text-decoration: none
        color: inherit
    header
        h1
            margin-bottom: 0
        p
            margin-top: 0

    .row
        +flex(row wrap, space-around)
    .col
        +flex(column wrap, center)

    button.btn
        border: none
        +size($btn-width, $btn-height)
        background: $color-theme
        border-radius: 5px 
        margin: auto
        color: inherit
        font-family: inherit
        font-size: inherit
        transition: all 0.25s
        border-bottom: 0px solid $color-theme
    button.btn:hover
        background: darken($color-theme, 10%)
        border-bottom: 5px solid darken($color-theme, 20%)
        cursor: pointer
    button.btn:focus
        outline: none

    button.btn ~ [class*="-ghost"]
        border: 0px solid $color-theme
        +size($btn-width, $btn-height)
        background: $color-theme
        border-radius: 5px 
        margin: auto
        color: inherit
        font-family: inherit
        font-size: inherit
        transition: all 0.25s
        border-bottom: 0px solid $color-theme
    button.btn ~ [class*="-ghost"]:hover
        background: transparent
        border: 2px solid $color-theme
        cursor: pointer
        color: $color-theme
    button.btn ~ [class*="-ghost"]:focus
        outline: none

    button.btn ~ [class*="-pill"]
        border: 0px solid $color-theme
        +size($btn-width, $btn-height)
        background: $color-theme
        border-radius: 25px 
        margin: auto
        color: inherit
        font-family: inherit
        font-size: inherit
        transition: all 0.25s
        border-bottom: 0px solid $color-theme
    button.btn ~ [class*="-pill"]:hover
        cursor: pointer
        +size($btn-width * 1.5, $btn-height)
        overflow: hidden
        position: relative
        &:before
            content: ''
            display: block
            @extend [class*="-pill"]
            background: lighten($color-theme, 10%)
            position: absolute
            top: 0
            left: 100%
            animation: pill 1s
    button.btn ~ [class*="-pill"]:focus
        outline: none



    button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]
        border: 0px solid $color-theme
        +size($btn-width, $btn-height)
        background: $color-theme
        border-radius: 25px 
        margin: auto
        color: inherit
        font-family: inherit
        font-size: inherit
        transition: all 0.25s
        border-bottom: 0px solid $color-theme
    button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]:hover
        cursor: pointer
        +size($btn-width * 1.5, $btn-height)
        overflow: hidden
        position: relative
        &:before
            content: ''
            display: block
            @extend [class*="-fall"]
            background: lighten($color-theme, 10%)
            position: absolute
            top: 0
            left: 100%
            animation: pill 1s
    button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]:focus
        outline: none



    // Animations
    @keyframes pill
        0%
            left: 100%
        100%
            left: -100%
```

A few things are weird, for example, I used the `button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]` kind of selector to select the elements with the `-fall` word in their class etc. So that works for the first row of buttons but mysteriously that same code doesn't work for the second row. I'm not sure why it's happening so I tried to do something like this `button.btn[class*="-fall"]` and that didn't work either, so I tried to do something like `button[class*="-fall"]` and this solution actually works, so does `[class*="-fall"]`. What I'm really confused about now is why is the first and the second attempts like `button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]`
and `button.btn[class*="-fall"]` not working while the others are?

Can you guys please help me out if I'm missing anything? Did I misunderstand the usage of these selectors? How can I fix this?

Comment: The code in your pen does not match the code that's here. I'm assuming the code that's here is the right one since the ~ combinator does not appear anywhere in your pen.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh sorry, I was just fiddling around, lol I was trying to figure out!

Comment: And that is why I'm not a fan of CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of that `button.btn ~ [class*="-fall"]` would fail is that the only `[class*="-fall"]` is the first child of its parent `.row`. If there's only one, and it's the first child, then there are no elements before it and it won't match the sibling selector. This can be seen from your Pug code, specifically here:

```
.row
    button.btn-fall Kitty
    button.btn-hang World
    button.btn-wobble Cat
```

The reason `button.btn[class*="-fall"]` fails is because your buttons don't have the "btn" class. They each have one class that *starts with* "btn" but is not exactly "btn". So `.btn-fall` would match, but not `.btn`.

To make your life easier you can always modify your buttons so that they each have two classes instead of one compound class:

```
.row
    button.btn Hello
    button.btn.ghost World
    button.btn.pill Cat
.row
    button.btn.fall Kitty
    button.btn.hang World
    button.btn.wobble Cat
```

That way, every button will have a "btn" class and you can just use two class selectors to match elements instead of relying on an attribute substring selector, which is less idiomatic.

But then again, if every button is going to have the "btn" class anyway, it's... probably redundant.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I didn't think about the '.btn' class! Hah! Thank you!